# How to Open the dialog pop up in my Controller code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div in my master page.

```
 <div id="UICancelChanges" title="Are you sure?" style="display: none;">
            Your changes have not been saved. Are you sure you want to CANCEL ?
        </div>
```

On click I am just opening Jquery dialog popup window..

```
CancelEdit = function (accountId) {
            $("#UICancelChanges").dialog({
                resizable: true,
                height: 140,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        };
```

Is there any way that I can change the Title of this Div popup dynamically? using same code I need to change the title dynamically?

How to open my popup window in the controller code?something like this?

```
  return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "alert('SubCategory Successfully Added. Thank You.'); window.location='/ObnCategory/Index';" };
```

Instead of alert i need to open the popup window.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, you are asking two questions here. If you can keep your question to one, you're more likely to get a more focused answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this before you display the dialog

initialise:

```
$( "#UICancelChanges" ).dialog({ title: 'Dialog Title' });
```

to set the new title do

```
$( "#UICancelChanges" ).dialog( "option", "title", 'New Dialog Title' );
```

to get the title

```
var title = $( "#UICancelChanges" ).dialog( "option", "title" );
```

for more help on the properties visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-title

Comment: Thanks Bharath, how to display this popup dialog on  Return jsonresult? on my alert?

Comment: can you be abit more specific on what you're trying to achieve..from what i've understood you can do $('#UICancelChanges').dialog('open'); to open.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [jQuery UI website documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-title):

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "title", 'Dialog Title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

`$("span.ui-dialog-title").text(anything);`